Necessary and sufficient conditions for finding graphs based on posets
Let $\Gamma$ be any graph (say finite, simple, undirected), then denote by $P(\Gamma)$ the set of all non-isomorphic subgraphs of $\Gamma$. Let $\gamma$ be another graph, then denote $\gamma \subseteq \Gamma$ if and only if $\gamma$ is isomorphic to a subgraph of $\Gamma$. Now for any graph $\Gamma$ we have the poset $(P(\Gamma), \subseteq)$.
Here is my question: What are some nice sufficient conditions to guarantee that given a non-empty finite poset $(X, \leq)$ there is a graph $\Gamma$ with $(P(\Gamma), \subseteq) \cong (X, \leq)$ as posets? Additionally, what are some strong necessary conditions?
I’m aware that this question is very broad, and probably very difficult, but I’m eager to be surprised by StackExchange’s cunningness. I just found this question very interesting.

Here’s what I’ve found so far.
Sufficient:

If $(X, \leq)$ is totally ordered, then we can choose $\Gamma = (|X| - 1)\cdot K_1$.

Necessary:

$(X, \leq)$ must have a unique maximum and a unique minimum.

For $|X| \geq 3$ we must have unique elements $a_1 < a_2 < a_3$, where $a_1$ is the minimum $a_2$ is the minimum of $X\setminus \{a_1\}$, and $a_3$ is the minimum of $X\setminus \{a_1, a_2\}$.


Necessary (edit):

For $(X,\leq)$ there must exist a rank function making $X$ a graded poset. This has all sorts of implications. For example, all maximal chains must have the same length and $N_5$, the smallest non-modular lattice, isn’t a subposet of $X$. This holds, since $\rho(\gamma)=|V(\gamma)|+|E(\gamma)|$ is a rank function for $(P(\Gamma),\subseteq)$.

Every element of $X$ must be contained in a chain of maximal length (this also follows from the above).

The comparability graph of $(X,\leq)$ must be connected.



Addendum:
Another question I find very difficult and interesting is the following. Find non-isomorphic pairs of graphs $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ such that $(P(\Gamma_1),\subseteq)\cong (P(\Gamma_2),\subseteq)$ as posets. So far the only pair I’ve been able to find is $3\cdot K_1$ and $K_2$.

$X\setminus{a_1,a_2}$ does not have a unique minimum: $a_1$ is a graph with one vertex, $a_2$ has two vertices and no edges, but $a_3$ could have either two vertices and one edge or else three vertices and no edges. Or, if you're doing something weird like starting with the "null graph" (no vertices), you need to tell us; that usually isn't considered a graph.

Sorry, I guess we just use different conventions. My convention is that a graph is an ordered pair $(V,E)$ where $V$ can be any set including the empty set, etc. Wikipedia has the same convention by the way, so I really don’t think this is uncommon.
